# How to expand width of hovered slide in slick slider and set spacing for the first item?

Tags: javascript, css, slick.js

Am trying to do a netflix like slider but with different hover effect. Here's how the mockups look https://pasteboard.co/IGwDwLE.png

I also wonder why it gets off once I set the **variablewidth:true** for slidesToShow config.

I'd also like to have a spacing for the first item and when the user hit the next item i'll fill up that space like so https://pasteboard.co/IGwFVmy.png

I have this config of slick slider.

```
        $('.slider-inner').slick({
            dots: true,
            infinite: true,
            cssEase: 'linear',
            slidesToShow: 5,
            slidesToScroll: 5,
            arrows: true,
        });
```

Comment: Can you provide a runnable example of what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS pseudo class [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) can be used to define the style of elements in the slider on hover, and a negative right margin can achieve the positioning effect for the first element.

**When using `slick.js`, note the following:**

- The items in the slider are given a class `slick-slide`. Use it to target the slider elements in your stylesheets.
- Insert your own CSS after `slick-min.css` and `slick-theme-min.css` so that your custom styles override the default.
- Define the width of slide elements if you are using `variableWidth: true`.

Here's an example:

```js
$('.slider-inner').slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    cssEase: 'linear',
    arrows: true,
    variableWidth: true,
});
```

```css
.slider-outer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 70%;
  background: #ccc;
}
.slick-slide {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  background: white;
  border-left: 2px solid #ccc;
  width: 91px;
}
.slick-slide:hover {
  width: 130px;
  color: red;
  transition: .5s linear;
}
.first {
  margin-right: -50px; 
}
.first:hover {
  margin-right: 0px;
  transition: .5s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class='slider-outer'>
  <div class='slider-inner'>
    <div class='first'><h3>1</h3></div>
    <div><h3>2</h3></div>
    <div><h3>3</h3></div>
    <div><h3>4</h3></div>
    <div><h3>5</h3></div>
    <div><h3>6</h3></div>
    <div><h3>7</h3></div>
    <div><h3>8</h3></div>
    <div><h3>9</h3></div>
    <div><h3>10</h3></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```html
centerMode: true,
centerPadding: '60px'
```

[Live slick Demo](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the mockup design by using below settings of slick js

1. centerMode -
   Enables centered view with partial prev/next slides. Use with odd numbered slidesToShow counts.
2. centerPadding - 
   Side padding when in center mode (px or %) and by default value is set to 50px.

You can find all slick configurations in below link

https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick#settings

Example

```
$(".single-item").slick({
   centerMode: true,
   centerPadding: '40px',
   slidesToShow: 3  
});
```

You can check the live example in below link

https://jsfiddle.net/afz0os4w/